# How do I set Item Level permission on an Issue List in Sharepoint 2007

Tags: 2007, list

I have a Sharepoint Issue List in which I need users to

Read All Items
But Edit Items created by them.
In Sharepoint normal List, We can do so by Advanced Settings -> Item Level Permission. This option is not available in Issue List.

I have even tried with the below Code:

```
 SPList list = web.Lists["Shared Documents"];
 list.ReadSecurity = 2;
 list.WriteSecurity = 2; 
 list.Update();
```

Can anyone suggest what else can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Item level permissions are largely a disaster waiting to happen.

If this is absolutely required you may have better luck writing and event receiver on the list that compares two fields (say author) and cancels the update event if they dont meet the criteria.